# C# or AS3 Custom world time

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, clock

I'm wondering how can I create  custom world time for a game.

like one hour = 30 minutes,
1 year = 6 months

6 custom months

I'm stucked, and I have no clue how to do it.

I known I can use timer event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your main game loop is something like:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop, false, 0, true);

var _timer = 0; // starts as zero
const WORLD_TIME_FACTOR:Number = 2;

function gameLoop(e:Event):void {
    // all your game logic happens here

    _timer++;
}


function getWorldTime():Number {
    return (_timer/stage.frameRate) * WORLD_TIME_FACTOR;
}

// later (you can adjust WORLD_TIME_FACTOR to be anything, 2 would indicate that the 
// game world happens twice as quick as in real life (like your examples)
// 

trace(getWorldTime()); // At 3 seconds real world, would trace 6

trace(getWorldTime()); // At 33 seconds real world, would trace 66
```

You would then format this number into minutes with something like:

```
const div60:Number = 1/60;
const div120:Number = 1/60/60;     
function format_time(value:Number):String {
    // x >> 0 is the same as int(x) but quicker
    var minutes:String = String((value* div60 >> 0) % 60);
    minutes = (minutes == "60") ? "00" : minutes;  
    minutes = (minutes.length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

    var seconds:String = String(value% 60);
    seconds = (seconds.length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return (value* div120 >> 0) + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

So finally you would have

```
 trace(format_time(getWorldTime())); // At 72 (1 minute, 12 secs) seconds real world, would trace 00:02:24
```

Comment: Note that in flash, you can't rely on `stage.frameRate` and counting frames, really. `frameRate` is at best a hint to the player stating the max number of frames you want. But there's no guarantee your swf will run at precisely, say, 30 FPS. You're better off calculating deltas. A handy and simple function for that is getTimer(). Capture the initial time, then, when the clock ticks again (enter frame, timer, whatever), call getTimer and substract the returned value to the previous one to get the elapsed time.

Comment: one question... why do I have to have a factor to divide???

function getWorldTime():Number {
    return (_timer/stage.frameRate) * WORLD_TIME_FACTOR;
}

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the milliseconds that passed since the epoch Jan,1 1970
Any call to this function afterwords would give you a time in milliseconds.
Subtract that from the original time and you have how many milliseconds that have passed.
Knowing that you can now factor in your conversion. EX 6 seconds = 1 minute

```
var startingTime:Number = Date.parse(new Date( ));
trace(startingTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to remember the timestamp and in-game date of the moment when your in-game time started, and then to calculate in-game date for given *moment*:
*milliseconds_of_double_time = moment.timestamp - start_timestamp*
*ingame_date = date_from_timestamp(start_date.timestamp + milliseconds_of_double_time * 2)*